# Dealing with frequent device Twin reads and throttling

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Inspired by [Azure IoT PCS Remote Monitoring repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-pcs-remote-monitoring-dotnet) I started working on my own IoT system based on Azure Iot Hub.

Similar to IoT PCS repository, I have an API endpoint (/api/devices) that returns a list of devices on the my IoT Hub - when client makes a request I use Microsoft.Azure.Devices SDK and RegistryManager to create a query and return a list of device twins. This API endpoint is used and consumed on my front end SPA app.

```
var result = await registryManager
                .CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices", 100)
                .GetNextAsTwinAsync(options);
```

This works great, however I discovered that if you run this query too often, quite fast you'll encounter
[throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling). I'm using S1 tier and, if I understand it correctly, I'm allowed to make up to 20 Twin queries every minute. This doesn't exactly scale well assuming my system and client base grows. Even on the higher tiers, the scale is not really that high.

The question is - how are you expected to deal with this limitation?

So far my best idea is to replicate IoT Hub device (Twin) data into CosmosDB/SQL Server and synchronize all the twin changes using [IoT Hub endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-endpoints). Then instead of querying IoT Hub directly, I'd query CosmosDb/SQL instead. I don't know if this approach would be any good or not though.

Comment: Why don't you subscribe to an event instead of querying manually? Is that a requirement? I believe ModuleClient has SetDesiredPropertyUpdateCallbackAsync where you can pass a callback to process newly reported data

Comment: The API I mentioned is consumed by my front end and used to render UI. For example, /api/devices endpoint returns a list of devices on IoT Hub which is then used to render table on my front end.

Comment: I see, in that case, i don't think it was design for that purpose. A mediator or middleware might be needed in between to circumvent the limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that subscribing to twin changes and replicating desired and reported to a db which is read often is a viable solution.

The pipeline looks something like this: IoT Hub `->` Message routing:Endpoint `->` Consumer `->` To Db `->` Fast unlimited reads.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is - how are you expected to deal with this limitation?

Based of the doc [Reference - IoT Hub quotas and throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling):

```
Throttle    Free, B1, and S1    B2 and S2       B3 and S3
--------------------------------------------------------------
Queries       20/min/unit       20/min/unit     1,000/min/unit
```

You can scale-out your queries increasing a number of unit (up to 200 units) using a portal or programmatically, for instance [REST PUT request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/createorupdate#iothubskuinfo) based on the needs.